# JIRA Kanban board how to ignore spikes in release

Tags: kanban, jira

My team is using a Jira Kanban board (Kanban methodology as well) for managing the workflow (changes/incidents/spikes/tasks) of a 'mature' software product.
When there are elements which require code changes in the 'Selected For Development' queue, it is straightforward to release them and make them show in the corresponding version. However, should spikes or tasks which don't require anything but investigation (and sometimes to reject the functionality proposed for investigation) also be included in releases?

Comment: What does it mean (to you) when a ticket is included in a release?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau in principle, that some code has been changed and deployed. Should I maybe enhance this definition to maintain consistency with other non-code related work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A spike can be done, whether a release is planned or not.

A release can be planned (and deployed) whether the spike is done or not.

So they are independent entities. It does not make any sense to include one in the other.

Comment: What column should I move my spike to when it is done? And how do I make it disappear from the board without deleting it and without including it in a release?

Comment: I have no idea what your board looks like or how you have configured it. Don't you have a "done" column or state?

Comment: Yes, but stories will be showing in the done column until they are released.

Comment: Jira is super configurable. Talk to your Jira Administrator about your workflow and how to make that happen in Jira. Personally, I would just create another state that takes items off the board (maybe "completed without release"). Or you just create a dummy release for all the tickets you don't want to actually release, in case your administrator is too slow or doesn't want to make that change.